# Twitter Locked. Alternatives to email appeals

Tags: twitter

What's the deal with Twitter recently?

I have a personal, `@MyRealName` account which I haven't used for a long time. When I log in using my real password and I'm prompted to add my phone number that I registered with. As it was about 9 years ago and I've changed my phone I don't know these details. I tried to appeal but the email address I used `myrealname@myowndomain.com` is no longer active so I have no way to access that account.

So recently I created a new account for business purposes, and with no warning, my account is `blocked` - even though I haven't used it yet! I appealed it ( but refuse to add my phone number ), and sent a follow up reply asking politely to unblock my account. 7+ days later, it's still blocked & I have received no emails.

With that in mind, as the name is now not available I changed the details of my business ( not yet operational so I have freedom to play around with names ), and this morning I set up 3 accounts for running purposes (`Main Account`,`Blog Account`,`Owner Account`). 10 minutes after registering, 2 of my 3 accounts are blocked.

I have again been through the whole appeal process and sent a follow up email, but based on my last attempt I fear that there is no hope of getting it unblocked. And again, the usernames are now unavailable.

Is there any other official way of getting your account unlocked, without having to add your phone number, and without having to go through the pointless appeals process?

Comment: Did you create theses accounts with the same email each time ?

Comment: Well yes, they are all part of the same business, so I used a `gmail` business account `(business+accounts.main@gmail.com)`

Comment: With that in mind @PaulJ, in order of registration, it is the first and third accounts that are locked out, not the second.